# Можно ли на линуксе собрать .msi пакет, который умеет после установки настраивать службу на windows(или умеет в пост скрипты)?

Tags: linux, package, msi

Необходимо линуксе собрать msi пакет для Windows.
Надо что бы после установки этот пакет сам настраивал службу или по крайней мере умел запускать post-скрипт.\

Хотелось найти какое-то решение что бы собирать такие пакеты без графического интерфейса (планирую делать это в контейнере)

Нагуглил wixpy облазив всю документацию понял что он видимо так не умеет.

Comment: https://github.com/suchja/wix-toolset как вариант. Минимум как точно отправки. Сам не юзал, если чё.

Comment: А ещё можешь написать в саппорт https://bell-sw.com/ - они свою сборку жабы делают, в том числе и под винду именно в msi.